# .NET 6 Rider Solution Template

Tags: c#, .net, rider

Is there a possibility to create a solution template including a Solution Folder and multiple files in .NET 6 for Jetbrains Rider? So far, I only found project templates that can be defined.

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, yes! Rider makes it super easy to create custom templates. [Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Creating_and_Opening_Projects_and_Solutions.html#create-custom-project-template) you can find a detailed step-by-step instruction within the official docs.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already tried this, but there you only can define project-level templates, but I want to create a template for an empty solution with predefined files in a solution folder (e.g. .gitignore, .gitlab-ci.yml, GitVersion.yml). Is there also a possibility to define this type of template?

Comment: I assume that's gonna be difficult, as this is not .NET content. But it seems to me that [`dotnet new` templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/cli-templates-create-project-template) should be able to do this. Did you try them?